# Divergence theorem and green's identities usage for calculating integral over manifold

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, divergence-operator

Let $q=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and denote $f(x)$ as the squared distance of $x$ from $q$. Compute 
$$\int_{S^2} f(x) dS $$

**attempt**:

Since $f \in C^1 $ we know $\nabla f $ is a smooth vector field. So apply the divergence theorem to get: 
$$\int_{S^2} \langle \nabla f , N \rangle dS = \int_{\mathbb{B}^3} \triangle fdx$$

Now:

- $\nabla f(x) = 2(x-q)$  hence $\lvert \nabla f \rvert = 2 \lVert x-q\rVert$
- $N = outward\ normal = x$
- $\triangle f = 6$

$\langle \nabla f , N \rangle = \langle \nabla f , x-q+q \rangle = 2f + \langle \nabla f , q \rangle$

I don't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Here's one very easy way to proceed a little farther. When applying the divergence theorem, the right hand side is an integral not over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but only over the unit 3-ball $B^3$. You should then be able to evaluate the right hand side exactly.

Comment: And then to proceed still a little further, on the left hand side of the divergence theorem, use your final equation to substitute for $\langle \nabla f , N \rangle$.

Comment: Im sorry, of course... this was a typo.. but what about $\langle \nabla f , q \rangle $ in left hand side ?

Comment: Since $q$ is a constant, and since you have a very concrete formula for $\nabla f$, it should be easy to evaluate the integral of $\langle \nabla f , N \rangle$.